# Solving a many-to-one assignment problem with additional constraints

Tags: discrete-optimization

Assume there are $M$ items and $N$ people with $M \ge N$.  A single item can be
assigned to more than one person; however, item $i$ cannot be assigned more than
$d_i$ times in total.  Furthermore, each item has a category $c_i$ and a single
person cannot be assigned two or more items of the same category.

The assignment of item $i$ to person $p$ produces value $v_{i, p}$.  I would
like to find an assignment which maximizes the total value.

It should be fairly simple to write this as an, e.g., [MiniZinc
model](http://www.minizinc.org/).  What I am interested is whether this
resembles some optimization problem that has already been researched.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is actually more manageable with a greedy approach: 
1) short the $v_{i,p}$ values into a list
2) for each person $p$ keep a category table where $u_p(x)=1$ if category $x$ is used and $0$ otherwise.
3) starting from the top assign the maximum value $v_{i,p}$ to the total sum if $d_i>0$ and the category of item $i$ is not used by person $p$ and then assign $d_i:=d_i-1$ and set $u_p(x)=1$.
4) the algorithm terminates when you reach the bottom value and takes time $MN$.
It isn’t hard to prove that the correctness of this algorithm.

Comment: How would this maximize the total value?

Comment: Because maximum flow implies maximum matching in your person-item graph. The item category nodes are just for the additional $c_i$ constraints. If you read the max flow min cut algorithm on Wikipedia you will find all sorts of such applications.

Comment: Yes, but the flow is in no way influenced by the values $v_{i, p}$.

Comment: I thought $v_{i,p}$ was $1$ or $0$ depending on if a path person-category-item exists (has flow coming through it) or doesn’t exist

Comment: If I misunderstood your question please provide more details on what $v$ is

Comment: No -- as I said, $v_{i, p}$ is the value/utility person $p$ gets from being assigned item $i$.

Comment: Ok then, since I am writing from a mobile device I will delete or edit my answer as soon as I get back to desktop.

Comment: I think you could still pull this off with a greedy approach where you start from each person and follow the flow path all the way to the optimal item from each category that was chosen. As I said though I will try to edit this into a complete answer.